# <div></div> и <div/> в чем разница?

Tags: html

Есть два примера. Почему в первом примере показует 3 блока, в то время как во втором примере показует один?

  1.

```html
<html>

<head>
 <style>
  body {
   margin: 0;
  }
  
  .my {
   background-color: green;
   height: 100px;
   width: 200px;
   margin: 10px;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="my"></div>
 <div class="my"></div>
 <div class="my"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

  2.

```html
<html>

<head>
 <style>
  body {
   margin: 0;
  }
  
  .my {
   background-color: green;
   height: 100px;
   width: 200px;
   margin: 10px;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="my" />
 <div class="my" />
 <div class="my" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: он там не один, он вкладывается один в другой. есть тэги которые парные, к ним относится `div`. Есть одиночные, `input`, `br` и т.п. То как браузер показывает невалидный html на совести браузера. В данном случае трактуется как открывающие тэги, без закрывающих.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`div` относится к тэгам-контейнерам и требует парного закрывающего тэга. В вашем примере во втором случае, закрывающие тэги отсутствуют, поэтому блоки просто вложены один в другой.

приведу [пару цитат](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/tegi)

> Теги бывают двух типов — одиночные и парные (контейнеры). Одиночный
>   тег используется самостоятельно, а парный может включать внутри себя
>   другие теги или текст
>
> Парные теги, называемые по-другому контейнеры, состоят из двух частей
>   — открывающий и закрывающий тег. Открывающий тег обозначается как и
>   одиночный — `<тег>`, а в закрывающем используется слэш — `</тег`>.
>   Допускается вкладывать в контейнер другие теги, однако следует
>   соблюдать их порядок.
>
> Не все контейнеры требуют обязательно закрывающего тега, иногда его
>   можно и опустить.

что касается закрытия `/>` то это не валидный HTML-синтаксис.  Данная конструкция относится к XML, так что браузеры попросту игнорируют этот слэш в конце. В HTML-тэги либо не закрываются, либо закрываются парным закрывающим `</tag>`

```css
.my {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;      
}
    
.red {background-color: red;}
.green {background-color: green;}
.blue {background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<div class="my red" />
<div class="my green" />
<div class="my blue" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Там три блока на самом деле, просто т.к. браузер не видит закрывающего тега, он вкладывает их друг в друга и они друг на друга накладываются, потому может показаться, что только один блок отрисован. Это можно было бы понять, взглянув на код страницы с браузере.
Результат такой из-за того, то в большинстве браузеров не предусмотрена такая вот конструкция.